# putting text a little bit lower on my website

Tags: html, web, text, styles

I would like to get this text a little bit lower.

```
<div style="text-align:center"><h1><b>Welcome</b></h1></div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.welcome {
  margin-top:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome"><h1><b>Welcome</b></h1></div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp I would suggest you to go on w3schools to learn more!